# Will Ubuntu recognise both internal disks and the separate partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have an oldish, but high spec, PC which has two internal hard drives. The original drive has three partitions. It is dual booted Windows XP and 7. The other partition is just for data. There's a second large hard drive with lots of data on. I want to install Ubuntu on the main XP partition and just want to know if all the other partitions/drives will be viewable from Ubuntu as life will be a bit simpler if I can access all the data from there. I do have everything backed up elsewhere of course. I am very vigilant protecting my data.

Comment: Ubuntu will read and write ntfs, fat32, and other MS file systems.  If nothing was encrypted using WinXP or Win7. Keep a watchful eye on the partition you are installing to because not every program numbers the partitions the same. The install should go fairly easy for you. I recommend using a long term release Ubuntu like 16 for stability reasons. Oh you may need the 32 bit version check your hardware.

Comment: If your data is important, make a backup, the installer can over write data if you make a mistake. In addtition, make sure you understand linux partitions before you install. Linux does NOT use terms such as C: or D: , it uses /dev/sdXY

Comment: Very many thanks for that help. I’ve dabbled with Linux before a bit, but I’m not very confident and still struggle with some of the language. I think I’ll give it a go because despite my being very good at Windows maintenance, the whole set-up is getting a bit ‘sticky’ now and I can’t be completely confident that some of my 10 year old PC hardware is still OK, so I’ll see if everything works on Linux as I’m still resisting Windows 10 at the moment. I’ve got a windows laptop to fall back on if necessary.